# How to create and initiate an AWS S3 MultipartUpload in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

If I read the docs right, Boto3 has a low level client interface and a higher level resource one.
I can see how to create Buckets and Objects, but if I want a MultipartUpload (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#multipartupload) there seems to be no way to initiate it?  If I try and make a MultipartUploadPart and do an upload it complains I've not initiated it.

I guess I can use the client's create_multipart_upload to kick it off - but am I missing something or is this an oversight in boto3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that I've not tried this yet - I have just found http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.initiate_multipart_upload which implies you make an object and initiate from that